# OpenDDS - DCPSInfoRepo is killed but the publisher and subscriber are communicating

Tags: data-distribution-service, opendds

I'm exercising with `OpenDDS` DCPS examples from `OpenDDS-3.11/examples/DCPS/IntroductionToOpenDDS` on `Ubuntu 16`. As per the `AAA_README.txt` found in the same location, I first started `DCPSInfoRepo` `OpenDDS-3.11/bin/DCPSInfoRepo   -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:12345` followed by `subscriber` and `publisher` respectively.

I could get the `publisher` publishing and `subscriber` receiving the subscribed topics. I understand the `DCPSInfoRepo` creates `repo.ior` which will contain the participant's entry.

But if I kill the `DCPSInfoRepo`, I could see the `publisher` and `subscriber` continue to communicate but obviously could not add another participant as `DCPSInfoRepo` is not running.

I would like to know why the `publisher` and `subscriber` continue to communicate in the absence of `DCPSInfoRepo`. Don't we need `DCPSInfoRepo` server after participants are added? please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DCPSInfoRepo is only used for discovery, at the moment publishers/subscribers know of each other they will keep communicating even without the DCPSInfoRepo.

I would recommend you to use the RTPS discovery which is coming from the DDS standard. That removes the need for the DCPSInfoRepo completely (which is a single point of failure).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, I understand the role of DCPSInfoRepo. Thanks for the hint about RTPS, but would it support end points connected over TCP or only UDP. I'm fairly new to DDS. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.